# Regex help finding blocks of text using search words spread across multiple lines

Tags: c#, regex, text

Say I have the following block of text:

```
ONE asd blah| 1| 123| 222| -0.03| -62333| -2253| -121.26| -1120.12| XCT
TWO Three
Nine Twelve
Twenty
DDD

ONE ads blah| 42| 555| 5423| -345| -5422| -399815| -345| -345| XCT
TWO Three
Six Seven
Twenty
DDD
```

Now, I want to find the block of text that has all of the following:

```
ONE, TWO, Three, Nine, Twelve, Twenty
```

So that should match the first block but not the second

And then, likewise:

```
ONE, TWO, Three, Six, Seven, Twenty
```

Would match the 2nd block but not the 1st.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried to search for all text from `ONE` up to but not including the next `ONE` using:

```
ONE((.|\n)*)(?=^ONE)
```

As a start but even that doesn't work!

Comment: What is the programming language and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm using regex101 atm - it'll end up in c# though - I've been bashing my head against the wall trying out various things from http://www.regular-expressions.info/ but my knowledge of regex is seriously lacking :/

Comment: The whole thing is that you do not need a regex to get what you need in C#.

Comment: this is for processing huge chunks of text with lots of different rules - doing this in c# would be pretty messy :/

Comment: Sorry, doing it with a regex will be messier. Hope you will get help. If not, add a C# tag.

Comment: Added the tag anyway :) - I'll have a think about doing it in c# - if it's cleaner then that's obviously the way to do it

Comment: Is the order of the terms you're matching the same as the order in which they occur?

Comment: Here is a non-regex solution that can further be improved - https://ideone.com/n7IREf

Comment: @TimPietzcker yeah - always in the order specified

Comment: So, what do you think of  my non-regex solution? I only used 2 `Contains` but more can be added, certainly.

Comment: I think it would be easy to extend to what I need but I'm swaying towards the regex method for now because i can construct the rules quite easily with some find / replace magic + excel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that these terms always have to occur in order, it's easy:

```
ONE(?:(?!ONE).)*?TWO(?:(?!ONE).)*?Three(?:(?!ONE).)*?Nine(?:(?!ONE).)*?Twelve(?:(?!ONE).)*?Twenty(?:(?!ONE).)*
```

matches the first block but not the second. Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gL6pV3/1).

**Explanation:**

```
(?:(?!ONE).)*?
```

matches any number of characters unless they are at the start of the phrase `ONE`. This ensures that you don't cross over into a different block.

Make sure you compile the regex using `RegexOptions.Singleline` so the dot matches newlines.

Comment: That means that inside the block, you cannot have `ONE` substring.

Comment: Yes, it seems that that's what denotes the start of a new block. "all text from ONE up to but not including the next ONE"...

Comment: @TimPietzcker correct :) in fact it can be either of two things "ONE" or "ZZZ" for example

Comment: In that case, use `(?!ONE|ZZZ)`.

Comment: yep got it :) brilliant :)

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it's going to be easy to create all of the combinations I need - but the other answers blew me away too - i haven't found SO too useful in recent months but the response to this question amazed me - thank you to everyone that chipped in - I've really learned something today :)

Comment: @iwayneo Ask the right questions and you shall get good answers. This is still true, but signal-to-noise ratio is not as good as it once was.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=.*?\bONE\b)(?=.*?\bTWO\b)(?=.*?\bThree\b)(?=.*?\bNine\b)(?=.*?\bTwelve\b)(?=.*?\bTwenty\b).*\n\n
```

matches your first block. Apply in single line mode (modifier `s` in most regex literal notations, or a flag when constructing the regex object).

It's a list of conditions that have to be fulfilled (in any order) before `.*\n\n` eventually matches the block. Each condition is a positive look-ahead that searches for a single word.

See: https://regex101.com/r/sC4tR1/1

This isn't "perfect" because there is no block boundary detection. If block boundaries are regular in your string, you can expand the expression to incorporate them.

Another strategy would be to split the string into individual blocks up-front and run the expression on those blocks instead of on the entire string.

Comment: I do not think it will work [if the blocks are mixed](https://regex101.com/r/sC4tR1/2).

Comment: I said it had no block boundary detection and that the OP must either add that or split the blocks up-front.

Comment: What do you mean by block boundaries? Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Where one block ends and another block begins, that's a block boundary. It isn't clearly defined in your question, so I did not build any mechanics to deal with that. It's also a "lesser problem" which I am sure you can figure out on your own.

Comment: I can easily combine rows.  I wasn't sure why you are looking at one ONE in the first row but taking all the words in the other rows.  You are just posting sample data and without seeing the real data I though it was a waste of my time to figure out what you haven't told us.

Comment: OK - I can do some processing up front to gather the blocks that can then be tested - I think this is a great start

Comment: The regex is easily built from an array of strings, mapped through `Regex.Escape()` and joined with `"\b)(?=.*?\b"`. Splitting the input up-front has the advantage of keeping the expression simpler and more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I've been parsing text like this for 40 years.  Regex usually cannot be used.  Try code like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            Block block = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (inputLine.StartsWith("ONE"))
                    {
                        block = new Block();
                        Block.blocks.Add(block);
                    }
                    block.lines.Add(inputLine);
                }
            }
        }
     }
    public class Block
    {
        public static List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>(); 
        public List<string> lines { get; set; }
        public Block()
        {
            lines = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is rather incomplete. You are not reading multiline blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to extract specific words from specific text structures (regular expression test/match), or are you trying to see if specific words are in the text given (as you seem to know which words you are looking for)

If it's the latter, how about AhoCorasic?

I have used this in the past. It is very, very fast algorithm of searching text for particular set of strings.

```
// Copyright (c) 2013 Pēteris Ņikiforovs
// 
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
// 
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// 
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Trie that will find and return strings found in a text.
    /// </summary>
    public class Trie : Trie<string>
    {
        public Trie(){}

        public Trie(IEnumerable<string> source)
        {
            Add(source);
            Build();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">The string to add.</param>
        public void Add(string s)
        {
            Add(s, s);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds multiple strings.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strings">The strings to add.</param>
        public void Add(IEnumerable<string> strings)
        {
            foreach (string s in strings)
            {
                Add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Trie that will find strings in a text and return values of type <typeparamref name="T"/>
    /// for each string found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">Value type.</typeparam>
    public class Trie<TValue> : Trie<char, TValue>
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Trie that will find strings or phrases and return values of type <typeparamref name="T"/>
    /// for each string or phrase found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <typeparamref name="T"/> will typically be a char for finding strings
    /// or a string for finding phrases or whole words.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of a letter in a word.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value that will be returned when the word is found.</typeparam>
    public class Trie<T, TValue>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Root of the trie. It has no value and no parent.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Node<T, TValue> root = new Node<T, TValue>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a word to the tree.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// A word consists of letters. A node is built for each letter.
        /// If the letter type is char, then the word will be a string, since it consists of letters.
        /// But a letter could also be a string which means that a node will be added
        /// for each word and so the word is actually a phrase.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="word">The word that will be searched.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value that will be returned when the word is found.</param>
        public void Add(IEnumerable<T> word, TValue value)
        {
            // start at the root
            var node = root;

            // build a branch for the word, one letter at a time
            // if a letter node doesn't exist, add it
            foreach (T c in word)
            {
                var child = node[c];

                if (child == null)
                    child = node[c] = new Node<T, TValue>(c, node);

                node = child;
            }

            // mark the end of the branch
            // by adding a value that will be returned when this word is found in a text
            node.Values.Add(value);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs fail or fall links.
        /// </summary>
        public void Build()
        {
            // construction is done using breadth-first-search
            var queue = new Queue<Node<T, TValue>>();
            queue.Enqueue(root);

            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var node = queue.Dequeue();

                // visit children
                foreach (var child in node)
                    queue.Enqueue(child);

                // fail link of root is root
                if (node == root)
                {
                    root.Fail = root;
                    continue;
                }

                var fail = node.Parent.Fail;

                while (fail[node.Word] == null && fail != root)
                    fail = fail.Fail;

                node.Fail = fail[node.Word] ?? root;
                if (node.Fail == node)
                    node.Fail = root;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds all added words in a text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The text to search in.</param>
        /// <returns>The values that were added for the found words.</returns>
        public IEnumerable<TValue> Find(IEnumerable<T> text)
        {
            var node = root;

            foreach (T c in text)
            {
                while (node[c] == null && node != root)
                    node = node.Fail;

                node = node[c] ?? root;

                for (var t = node; t != root; t = t.Fail)
                {
                    foreach (TValue value in t.Values)
                        yield return value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Node in a trie.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TNode">The same as the parent type.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TNodeValue">The same as the parent value type.</typeparam>
        private class Node<TNode, TNodeValue> : IEnumerable<Node<TNode, TNodeValue>>
        {
            private readonly TNode word;
            private readonly Node<TNode, TNodeValue> parent;
            private readonly Dictionary<TNode, Node<TNode, TNodeValue>> children = new Dictionary<TNode, Node<TNode, TNodeValue>>();
            private readonly List<TNodeValue> values = new List<TNodeValue>();

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor for the root node.
            /// </summary>
            public Node()
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Constructor for a node with a word
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="word"></param>
            /// <param name="parent"></param>
            public Node(TNode word, Node<TNode, TNodeValue> parent)
            {
                this.word = word;
                this.parent = parent;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Word (or letter) for this node.
            /// </summary>
            public TNode Word
            {
                get { return word; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Parent node.
            /// </summary>
            public Node<TNode, TNodeValue> Parent
            {
                get { return parent; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Fail or fall node.
            /// </summary>
            public Node<TNode, TNodeValue> Fail
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Children for this node.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="c">Child word.</param>
            /// <returns>Child node.</returns>
            public Node<TNode, TNodeValue> this[TNode c]
            {
                get { return children.ContainsKey(c) ? children[c] : null; }
                set { children[c] = value; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Values for words that end at this node.
            /// </summary>
            public List<TNodeValue> Values
            {
                get { return values; }
            }

            /// <inherit/>
            public IEnumerator<Node<TNode, TNodeValue>> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return children.Values.GetEnumerator();
            }

            /// <inherit/>
            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }

            /// <inherit/>
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Word.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to really look into this and will probably use it in the future - it's a very interesting implementation - thank you for the time you spent to help me out :)